# Kunagi LDAP configuration problems

Tags: ldap, java

We recently started with Scrum at our company and we wanted to start using Kunagi to test and see how it works.

So I installed the `kunagi_0.23.2.deb` package that I downloaded from their website, on my Ubuntu 11.04 running in tomcat6 using openjdk-6-jre.

Everything works fine except I can't get the LDAP to work. I have one AD server and one LDAP at my disposal for testing. For the LDAP I use the following info:

- uri: ldap://192.168.1.11:389
- user: some_tested_user
- passwd: the_pass
- DN: dc=colosa,dc=net
- LDAP Filter: (&(objectClass=user))

I tested various LDAP Filters, I don't know if I have the right one. However I get an error when clicking "test LDAP". The error refers to the DN:

```
Server service call error
Calling service TestLdap failed.
java.lang.RuntimeException: InvalidNameException: [LDAP: error code 34 - invalid DN]
```

With the AD server I get no error while testing, yet I am not able to login I get: "Login failed" every time. I don't know if this is because of the LDAP Filter I entered, yet I can't get it to work.

I have read [this page](http://kunagi.org/iss652.html) stating that I need to create my accounts inside Kunagi before I can login. So I did this with no effect.

So basically my question is, what causes this DN string error (I am sure mine is right), and what LDAP Filter should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Error code 34](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#appendix-A) is an indication that the server to which the LDAP client is connecting has determined that the distinguished name is not of the correct syntax. From the question, `dc=colosa,dc=net` appears to have the correct syntax for a distinguished name. Check that the configuration has that value (perhaps a typo?).

Also, if the `user` listed is a distinguished name (it could be for a base level search and the application considers a distinguished name in the user field to imply a base level search), verify that is a valid distinguished name.

Use the `ldapsearch` command line tool to verify that the parameters used by the configuration are correct. For more information on `ldapsearch`, see [LDAP: Using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/). For example:

```
ldapsearch -xLLL -H ldap://192.168.1.11:389 \
 -D user -w password -b dc=colosa,dc=net -s sub \
 '(objectClass=user)' 1.1
```

The filter listed is a valid filter, though the simpler filter `(objectClass=user)` could be used.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am most def on step further!! It turns out that the "dc=colosa,dc=net" needed to be "DC=colosa,DC=net":S It returns nothing yet, the filter is wrong (* returns a lot). I will try and look into this filter stuff a bit more.

I am sorry that I can't vote this answer one up, my reputation is to low. I will try and gather some and give you a vote!